# beforeValidation() didn't invoke for creating a record

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, sails.js, waterline

beforeValidation() didn't invoke when the `Model.create(obj)` was called.

```
modele.exports = {
 attributes : {},
 beforeValidation : function(values, next){
  console.log("Hello I am here"); //it didn't invoke when Model.create(obj)exec(); was called
 }
}
```

I am using sails 0.10.0-rc4 and Waterline 0.10.0-rc3.

Thank you.

Update :

Solution : [sails beforeValidation not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480072/sails-beforevalidation-not-called)

Comment: possible duplicate of [sails beforeValidation not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480072/sails-beforevalidation-not-called)

Comment: @ScottGress Thank you, you are right. I  thought http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/guides/models should be synced with https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Models.md. Apparantly, they are not.

Comment: Those docs are in active development, but in general the *reference* section is synced with https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/, not *guides*.